# SSL in HttpClient

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x

I am using apache common version of HttpClient api (Common-HttpClient) were the implementation seems to be straight forward. For example, Specify proxy in easy manner and there is no difference in reading the web page content (http or https)

I find it hard to implement the same requirement if i upgrade HttpClient version to 4.5.x. I basically want to do things in the code [example](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/examples/org/apache/http/examples/client/ClientCustomSSL.java)

My question is why do we need SSL/KeyStore in this case of HttpClient 4.5.x? what do i need to do to generate a new keystore to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is why do we need SSL/KeyStore in this case of HttpClient 4.5.x? what do i need to do to generate a new keystore to make it work?

For your own sake you *should* know what trust / key material your application is supposed to use when making secure outbound connections. One does not need to generate a new keystore in order for SSL to work. One can simply use trust material shipped with the Java runtime.